# Two queries in one while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to collect two queries in one while loop?
I have tried the code below, but do not get the expected result.

```
<?php

    include 'conn.php';
    $query_answers=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM answers");


          while($row_answers=mysqli_fetch_array($query_answers)){
    ?>
            <table>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $row_answers['answer_text'];?>"></td>
              <td><select>
                <option>
                    <?php 
                    $query_question = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id= ".$row_answers['next_question_id']."");
                    while($row_answers=mysqli_fetch_array($query_question)){
                        echo $query_question['question_text'];
                    }
                    ?>

                </option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
    <?php

            }

          ?>
```

Comment: Possible yes. But if needed it is a sign of a bad DB scheme. You should use `join`s. The issue you have though is you are using the same variable name so the result set is overwritten.

Comment: You are defining `$row_answers` in both loops.  I think your inner loop should use `$row_questions` or something like that instead.  And as mentioned above, you could write this in a single query if you would prefer and handle the logic accordingly within the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `row_answers` variable instead of using a different one for the question's query. Additionally, you are referencing the query instead of its result in the loop:

```
while ($row_questions = mysqli_fetch_array($query_question)) {
    echo $row_questions['question_text'];
}
```